# how to replace row values with conditional statement in R

Tags: r, replace

I'm having 3 columns Seq, Period and Treatment.
Sequence has values ABB,BBA,BAB,.. i.e. 1A and 2B combination.
Period has 3 values i.e. 1,2 & 3
and Treatment will have value based on the Period and Sequence
eg. if Sequence is ABB and Period is 1 then Treatment will be A
if Sequence is ABB and Period is 2 then Treatment will be B
similarly if Sequence is ABB and Period is 3 then Treatment will be B.
following is the snapshot of the data

```
 Sequence Period Treatment   
    BBA      1         B  
    BBA      2         B  
    BBA      3         A 
    ABB      1         A 
    ABB      2         B 
    ABB      3         B
```

I want to Replace Treatment Value B of Sequence BBA and Period 1 with B1 and Sequence BBA and Period 2 with B2
similarly with the rest of the data.

I tried the following code

```
updatedata<-if((data$Sequence=='ABB' && data$Period==2) || (data$Sequence=='BAB' && data$Period==1) || (data$Sequence=='BBA' && data$Period==1)){
  data$Treatment<-'B1'
}else if((data$Sequence=='ABB' && data$Period==3) || (data$Sequence=='BAB' && data$Period==3) || (data$Sequence=='BBA' && data$Period==2)){
data$Treatment<-'B2'
}else((data$Sequence=='ABB' && data$Period==1) || (data$Sequence=='BAB' && data$Period==2) || (data$Sequence=='BBA' && data$Period==3)){
data$Treatment<-'A'}
```

I expect the following results

```
Sequence Period Treatment   
    BBA      1         B1  
    BBA      2         B2 
    BBA      3         A 
    ABB      1         A 
    ABB      2         B1
    ABB      3         B2
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Error: unexpected '{' in: "  data$Treatment<-'B2'
>    }else((data$Sequence=='ABB' && data$Period==1) ||
>    (data$Sequence=='BAB' && data$Period==2) || (data$Sequence=='BBA' &&
>    data$Period==3)){"

Comment: Shouldn't `else` be another `else if`?

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
z%>%mutate(Treatment=if_else(Treatment=="B",paste0("B",Period),Treatment))

1      BBA      1        B1
2      BBA      2        B2
3      BBA      3         A
4      ABB      1         A
5      ABB      2        B2
6      ABB      3        B3
```

**Edit**

Second version:

```
cond1 = z$Sequence=="BBA" & z$Treatment=="B"
cond2 = z$Sequence=="ABB" & z$Treatment=="B"
cond3 = z$Sequence=="BAB" & z$Treatment=="B"

z$Treatment[cond1]=paste0(z$Treatment[cond1],z$Period[cond1])
z$Treatment[cond2]=paste0(z$Treatment[cond2],z$Period[cond2]-1)
z$Treatment[cond3]=paste0(z$Treatment[cond3],
                          ifelse(z$Period[cond3]>2,2,1))
> z
   Sequence Period Treatment
2       BBA      1        B1
3       BBA      2        B2
4       BBA      3         A
5       ABB      1         A
6       ABB      2        B1
7       ABB      3        B2
8       BAB      1        B1
9       BAB      2         A
10      BAB      3        B2
```

data:

```
structure(list(Sequence = c("BBA", "BBA", "BBA", "ABB", "ABB", 
"ABB", "BAB", "BAB", "BAB"), Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 
2, 3), Treatment = c("B1", "B2", "A", "A", "B1", "B2", "B1", 
"A", "B2")), row.names = 2:10, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Any particular reason you used `dplyr::if_else` rather than base R `ifelse`?

Comment: @boski I just want B1 and B2 not B3 that too if in a sequence suppose ABB here fist B should be alloted B1 and second coming B should be replaced with B2
Similarly if sequence is BAB, fist B should be Replaced by B1 and  at Period 3 B should be Replaced by B2.

Comment: @Anamtasayyed is the order of the sequence always the same? can there be any variations? If not, the new code I added should do the work.

Comment: @boski order of the sequence will be either ABB, BBA or BAB, and Treatment will be alloted based on the Period. But if 2nd B is at Period 3 then it should not be replaced with B3 rather it should be replaced with B2 similarly if first B is at period 2, it should not be replaced with B2 but with B1 in Treatment

Comment: mm it would really make it easier if you put a toy example with most (if not all) variations + desired output, if possible

Comment: @boski can you share yout email id or something so that I can share with you, as I'm getting some trouble here or you mail me at theanamtas@gmail.com

Comment: @boski the second version of the code is working can you suggest it for sequence BAB also?

Comment: @Anamtasayyed no problem :) if this answers works for you, accept it as correct answer to close the question.

Comment: @boski Also Same way if I have 4 Periods and two Sequence ABAB and BABA so first A in treatment should be assigned to A1 second A must be A2 similarly first coming B should be assigned B1 and 2nd B would be B2